# How to Mock ILogger / ILoggerService using Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, prism, moq, moq-3

I'm writing some unit tests for my View Model class. The constructor of this class is injected with an ILoggerService. This interface defines 1 method GetLog which returns an ILogger. Something like below where ***this*** represents a class that implements ILoggable:-

```
protected ViewModelBase(ILoggerService loggerService)
    {
        Logger = loggerService.GetLog(this);
    }
```

I'm trying to unit test my CreateNewOrder method that looks like below:

```
private void CreateNewOrder(INewOrderViewModel newOrderViewModel)
    {
        Logger.Log("Sending Create New Order Message", LogCategory.Info);
        var createNewOrderMessage = new OrderMessage(newOrderViewModel);
        _eventAggregator.GetEvent<CreateOrderEvent>().Publish(createNewOrderMessage);
    }
```

How would I go about Mocking the ILoggerService so that a valid Logger is returned? At the moment my Unit test throws a NullReferenceExeception.

I'm using Moq to do my mocking.

I'm imagining I need to do something along the lines of

```
var loggerService = new Mock<ILoggerService>();
        loggerService.Setup(svc => svc.GetLog(??))
```

But I can't see how without making my test class implement ILoggable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If using Serilog, you can simply pass `Logger.None` to your class.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not sure what the type is of the `GetLog` method parameter, but I assume it's something like `object` so the logger service can determine the type requesting a logger. You can use `It` to  mock parameters in a method you are setting up, as seen below.

```
var logger = new Mock<ILogger>();

var loggerService = new Mock<ILoggerService>();
loggerService.Setup(c => c.GetLog(It.IsAny<object>())
     .Returns(logger.Object);
```

Then pass `logger.Object` to whatever method or type needs an `ILoggerService`.

Comment: For reference, I use something like : `var loggerMoq = Mock.Of<ILogger<MyClassName>>();`